# How to find radius of convergence of power series using root test?

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence, power-series

**Question**

Find the radius of convergence of the power series $$\sum^{\infty}_{n = 1} \left(1 + \frac 2 n\right)^{n^3} z^{n^2}$$ using the root test.

**My working**

I know that, in order to use the root test, we must have a positive-termed series, which we do here. Thus, we want to find $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[\left\lvert\left(1 + \frac 2 n\right)^{n^3} z^{n^2}\right\rvert\right]^{\frac 1 n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left[\left(1 + \frac 2 n\right)^{n^2} z^n\right].$$

Now, I am stuck. Am I correct so far? If so, then what should I do next?

Any intuitive explanations or suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Think in direction of convergence radius and  Cauchy–Hadamard with $\lim\sup$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem in place of limit, as here we have not all powers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that, in general, $z^{n^2}$ is not a positive real number. But $\left|z^{n^2}\right|$ is. And we have\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\left(1+\frac2n\right)^{n^3}z^{n^2}\right|}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac2n\right)^{n^2}|z|^n\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac2n\right)^n|z|\right)^n.\end{align}Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac2n\right)^n=e^2$, this limit is $0$ if $|z|<e^{-2}$ and $\infty$ if $|z|>e^{-2}$. Therefore, the radius of convergence is $e^{-2}$.

Comment: Sorry, but we take only coefficients in formula and limit from them seems is infinity, or I am wrong?

Comment: @zkutch I have no idea about what you are saying here.

Comment: $\frac{1}{R}=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\left( |c_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac2n\right)^{n^2}$

Comment: @zkutch That is wrong, since it assumes (wrongly) that $c_n=\left(1+\frac2n\right)^{n^3}$.

Comment: I did not wrote, that $c_n=\left(1+\frac2n\right)^{n^3}$, $c_n$ consists of $0$'s and not zeros on $n^2$ places. But $\limsup$ will be same. No?

Comment: @zkutch No, it will not, since, actually,$$c_n=\begin{cases}\left(1+\frac2{\sqrt n}\right)^{n^{3/2}}&\text{ if $n$ is a perfect square}\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139592/discussion-between-zkutch-and-jose-carlos-santos).